# Adding Footer at the end of Div having Position: Absolute

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

I have a webpage with following structure:

> ```
> div: (app) 
>
>     div: (navbar) 
>
>     div: (wrapper) {position: relative}
>
>         div: (intro) 
>
>         div: (content) {position: absolute}
>
>     div: (footer)
> ```

where div-content is dynamic that means it should extend if the data inside this div extends from its minimum height.

**I am trying to add the footer at the end of the content** but since content has absolute position, footer is being placed at the end of Intro.

I am beginner at front-end designing so pardon me if I am missing something basic. Please refer me some reading articles as well related to concepts about positioning divs.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #333;
}

.wrapper {;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid yellow;
}

.intro {
 height: 450px;
 background-color: blue;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 70px; 
/* align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 display: flex;*/
}

.content {
 position: absolute;
 top: 250px;
 width: 94%;
 right: 3%;
 left: 3%;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 6px; 
 box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(61,61,61,.15);
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: auto;

 min-height: 800px;
 background-color: gray;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
  background-color: red;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="app">
  <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="intro">Intro</div>
   <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: .content is overlapped with .intro intentionally. and that is why i am using position absolute for .content**

Comment: Remove `position: absolute`, you don't need it in that scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` from `.content`. This will fix the overlapping with the footer. The width will need to be adjusted accordingly (make `width: 100%`).

Updated: `.content`to span width

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #333;
}

.wrapper {;
  border: 4px solid yellow;
}

.intro {
 height: 450px;
 background-color: blue;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 70px; 
}

.content {
    margin: -250px auto auto;
 width: 94%;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 6px; 
 box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(61,61,61,.15);
    max-width: 906px;
 
 min-height: 800px;
 background-color: gray;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
  background-color: red;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="app">
  <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="intro">Intro</div>
   <div class="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want the content-div to overlap with intro-div that's why i am using position absolute.

Comment: @MAsadAli Updated it so there is the overlap, is this what you are after?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

delete your content min-height. is that what you need?

Comment: No. I want to place my footer at the end of content regardless of the size of content div.